# how to partition and install another distro side by side?

Tags: 18.04

I would like to know how to install another distro side by side with Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Currently 18.04.2 resides on the entire hard drive.  Would I need to make another partition?  How would I go about doing this?  Would I be able to use the same GRUB menu?

Comment: I usually boot a 'live' system (eg. your Ubuntu 18.04.2 install media) so the partition isn't in use, shrink it, then boot my other media (eg. 19.10 for testing purposes) and install it.  You can have multiple grub's installed (one for each), but only one will be active (ie. your bios selects which drive's MBR or first-sector is used).  You can use your existing, but the 'shrink' may have moved the /boot/grub/ location so I'd let the new install own grub, then you can also change this later if desired.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. Most systems since 2012 are UEFI hardware, but users do install in BIOS mode. You need  to be sure to install in same boot mode. If you want to share data between installs, best to have another data partition and keep / (root) smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is

(1) Shrink your existing partition:

I usually boot a 'live' system (eg. *your Ubuntu 18.04.2 install media*) so the partition isn't in use, shrink the existing partition(s) to create space.

(2) Install new system into created space:

Boot my other media (eg. *Ubuntu 19.10 for testing purposes*) and install it using the available space.  Most installs give you the option on where to put grub (which is what I use to select if you want to use it or not)

Notes on grub:

You can have multiple grub's installed (one for each), but only one will be active (ie. *your bios selects which drive's MBR or first-sector is used*). You can use your existing, but the 'shrink' (step 1) may have moved the /boot/grub/ location creating boot problems, so I'd usually opt to let the new install own grub, changing it later if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 different distros installed side by side. What i did i formatted my hard drive 40GB for each distro. 
at the installation windows chose `something else` and create a `EFI partition` (if your bios is in EFI mode), assign `300 MB`. Create a `/boot` partiotn and assign `500Mb` and lastly create a partition for root director at `/` mount point and assign the remaining space on your disk. and finally click on Drop down menu at the bottom `Device for boot loader installation`: and chose the boot partition we have just created in my case it's `/dev/sda8/`. install now. you should have all your distros listed while boot up.

Comment: Best not to share /boot or better not even have /boot as a partition. You may get conflicts if systems installed use same paths or kernels and one updates, but other is looking for old files.

Comment: Me too not sure whether a separate /boot partition is needed rather than only a root (`/`) mount point per each separate ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

First install the gparted from the ububtu software center and then partition your hard drive by using gparted and then install another distro on the new partition  by making bootable usb or dvd.

Answer (score 0):

First make a bootable usb stick with the distro, then boot to it and follow the instructions. Then it will ask you if you would like to install it along side ubuntu or replaces it. You choose along side and then use the partion tool in the installer to partion your drive. **Note you might want to make a back up of your drive in case you lose data**, I have done it allot and have not lost anything yet.