# Install Ubuntu next to deepin

Tags: dual-boot

I have been running Deepin for a while. I have enough space left to run Ubuntu and I would like to check it out. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: There is a question for such topic https://askubuntu.com/q/1141989/295286 however I would recommend installing Ununtu in virtualbox. I do the same - my main OS on hard drive is Deepin and Ubuntu 18.04 in virtual box. Having another distro on hard drive is nice for rescue but with that may come complications with bootloader, so if you just want to use Ubuntu for desktop purpose I would recommend virtual mavhine

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/142549/295286

Comment: "Checking out" Ubuntu is what a Live environment on the .iso is for. No installation needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the Ubuntu live CD (writing the ISO to a USB stick if necessary, there are tutorials for how to do that).  If you are able to run it without installing it to disk (via RAM and the livecd) and use the hardware on your machine without any issues, then you could proceed to the installation wizard.